# Django Template from Database Breaking on "Extends"

Tags: python, django, templates

So I have this Lander CMS system I'm building.  I want to be able to build dynamic templates:

```
class LanderTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    init_script = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    styles = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    javascript = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have this base template content constant, which has a couple params for "body", "styles", and "javascript":

```
CONTENT_BASE = """
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
{body}
{% endblock %}
{% block head_script %}
<style type="text/css">
{styles}
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block post_script %}
<script>
{javascript}
</style>
{% endblock %}"""
```

I have this function, which takes a Template model, turns it into kwargs, and generates a django Template object.

```
from django.template import Template
# Generate a lander template from the database
def get_db_template(template):
    data = template.__dict__
    content = CONTENT_BASE.format(**data)
    return Template(content)
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

> KeyError at /landers/view/
>
> '% extends "base'

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?  It seems like Python `string.format` is trying to parse the {% extends ...} as an arg?

Is that an accurate assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that is an acurate assumtion ... you will need to use `{{` if you want a literal { ... i think ... maybe `\{`